# Prototype declared function is not a function

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-programming

```
var AnArray=(function(){
    var anArray=[];

    AnArray.prototype.getAnArray=function(){
        return anArray;
    }

    AnArray.prototype.setArray=function(id,val){
        anArray[id]=val;
    }
});

var objAnArray=new AnArray();

console.log(objAnArray.getAnArray());
```

When I try to call `objAnArray.getAnArray();` it returns that it is not a function

However this below works fine

```
var Index=(function(){
    var Index=1;

    Index.prototype.getIndex=function(){
        return Index;
    }
    Index.prototype.setIndex=function(val){
        Index=val;
    }
});

var objIndex=new Index();

console.log(objIndex.getIndex());
```

Are prototypes unable to return arrays?

Comment: You called it `getArray()` not `getAnArray()`.

Comment: FWIW putting functions on the prototype *inside* the constructor is not really the right thing to do.

Comment: @Pointy typo, corrected. Problem remains

Comment: If you really fixed the typo it would work.

Comment: I only gain something if it works, and it doesn't.

Comment: Works here with the corrected code, exactly as above: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/pJjvvN

Comment: Here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVyPVL

Comment: @Cody That's different code. You left out the `objAnArray = new AnArray()` line (in your example above, and my pen); and you're trying to call the method directly on `AnArray`. If that's really what you're trying to do, update the example above to match.

Comment: Fixed it, still receiving error

Comment: So you're running the *same* code as in my link and your example (which don't throw the error), but still seeing the error? Have a link to CodePen or jsFiddle showing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `anArray` as an object, not an array. Use:

```
this.anArray = {}; // not []
```

---

Also your code looks weird. You declare the prototype in the constructor. Declare it like this instead:

```
function AnArray() {
    this.anArray = {};
}

AnArray.prototype.getArray=function(){
    return this.anArray;
}

AnArray.prototype.setArray=function(id,val){
    this.anArray[id]=val;
}
```

In your constructor you redeclare the prototype and bind the private variable `anArray` in every instance to the last instance of `AnArray`.

Same with `Index`.

This demonstrates the bad behaviour:

```
var AnArray=(function(){
    var anArray={};

    AnArray.prototype.getArray=function(){
        return anArray;
    }

    AnArray.prototype.setArray=function(id,val){
        anArray[id]=val;
    }
});
var a = new AnArray();
var b = new AnArray();
a.setArray("foo", "bar");
b.getArray(); // { foo: "bar" }
```

Comment: You're using `anArray` as an object, not an array. See my updated answer.

Comment: Marking this as the right answer, though I still have anArray=[];